# JupyterHub use logout does not stop docker container

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub

I successfully configured jupyterhub on google cloud using very basic DummyAuthenticator and Docker Spawner following this tutorial: https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub-deploy-docker
Everything is ok, but when the user logouts its docker container is still running. I was expecting that the container will be stopped when it is unused. It is a waste of resources for my taste. Is there any chance to trigger that behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think JupyterHub automatically deletes any services just by logging out.

But you can use **Cull-Idle**.
It provides a script to cull and shut down idle single-user notebook servers. And its pretty easy to use.

Link :

https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/tree/master/examples/cull-idle

Comment: JupyterHub has an option to do this, no need for cull-service. See my answer.

Comment: I think `c.JupyterHub.shutdown_on_logout` is added from v1.0.0 of jupyterhub. Anyway thanks for the update.

Answer (score 3):

I used this from the default configuration file jupyterhub generated.

### Shuts down all user servers on logout

c.JupyterHub.shutdown_on_logout = True

Culling should be used to shutdown inactive servers while the user is still logged in.